# How do I interactively create SQLite table from SQL Results

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I am trying to build a SQLite database using data from a production Oracle database.  The resulting dataset from the query is too large to fit into memory, so I want to insert the dataset in SQLIte to create analyses and summaries in R.  I have read the RSQLite documentation and haven't been able to come up with a solution.  Below is my attempt but it does not work. How do I interactively load a dataset as a table in SQLite?

```
library(RJDBC)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

### production oracle connection strings
drv <- JDBC(WORKING ORACLE DRIVER ASSIGNMENT)
con <- dbConnect(drv, WORKING ORACLE CONNECTION)

### SQLite connection string
my_db <- dbConnect(RSqlite::SQLite(),test_db)
### query from production system
prod_data <- paste("CREATE TABLE table1 AS 
    select distinct field1, field2, field3
    from oracle$production 
    where field1 > 0")

### execute query and create the table in SQLite with the data
dbWriteTable(my_db, prod_data, prod_data)
exec <- dbSendQuery(my_db, prod_data)
dbFetch(exec)
```

Comment: Not to be the bearer of bad news, but R basically operates entirely in memory.  This means that if the output from your Oracle query can't fit in memory...then it also can't fit in R.  If I were you, I would probably just dump your Oracle table to CSV, then load it into SQLite.  I don't even think that R necessarily has to play a role here.  I'll stop talking now :-X

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim.  I am coming from SAS where I used the work space to create temporary tables for this purpose.  I was hoping I could use RSQlite as a similar alternative in R :(

Comment: You should be able to do this using `dplyr`, `odbc`, `DBI` and `dbplyr`. This allows you to analyse your database data without loading it fully into R's memory. See here for more info (check the "Quick Example" section): https://db.rstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @meenaparam This looks like a possibility, however my sql to extract the data from oracle has complex joins and nested joins.  Does dplyr work with standard SQL or just the dplyr verbs?  Is there additional documentation or examples you can point me to?

Comment: @Brad_J Take a look at the examples on p12 of the dbplyr help file. Basically, you can use raw SQL if you want. https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dbplyr/dbplyr.pdf This might also be helpful http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dbplyr.html

Comment: Thanks @meenaparam !